# How to ignore some special requests explicitly when using charles?

Tags: charles-proxy

When started `charles`, java app cannot access `redis` got below error

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

[image]

Then I tried to ignore the redis connection to solve it

[image]

but the problem still exists

So how to explicitly ignore some connection, e.g redis connection, mongo connection etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't really know what your real problem is. I guess the problem that you have is those HTTP requests still appearing in the *Structure* view, right?

Being that the case, I would strongly recommend you to use the **Focus** feature. To use it, you only need to add the domain you are working on to the *View* -> *Focused Hosts...* ( you can also do it by right clicking on the request and then selecting *"Focus"*).

By doing this, all the non-focused domains will get grouped in a *"Other hosts"* entry in the *Structure* panel so they won't disturb your work anymore.

Comment: No, actually I want is that charles could ignore `socket://192.168.0.77:8974` completely, when my app access redis server it like the charles does not exist.

Comment: what do you mean by "ignore"? as soon as you tell you applications to use Charles' proxy it will have to handle all the requests coming from them. If you say "ignore" just as "make charles to just let http requests go back and forth" then it actually is what it does by default. If your requests fail only when using charles then the cause may not be in charles, but in the apps, could it?